# How do i make animation like this website http://fitch.com

Tags: css

How do I make animation like http://fitch.com see the top, right side, bottom and left side. its look like loading..

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style> 
.topLoader {
width: 100%;
height: 5px;
background-color: #fff;
position: relative;
-webkit-animation-name: example; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
-webkit-animation-duration: 4s; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
animation-duration: 2s; 
animation-name: mytop ;
}
.bottomLoader {
width: 100%;
height: 5px;
background-color: #fff;
position: relative;
-webkit-animation-name: example; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
-webkit-animation-duration: 4s; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
animation-duration: 2s; 
animation-name: mybottom  ;
}
@keyframes mytop {
0%    {background-color:#000000; left:0px; top:0px;}
100%   {background-color:#000000; left:100%; top:0px;}
}
@keyframes mybottom {
0%  {background-color:#000000; left:100%; top:100%;}
100%  {background-color:#000000; left:0px; top:100%;}
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="topLoader"></div><br>
<div class="rightLoader"></div><br>
<div class="leftLoader"></div><br>
<div class="bottomLoader"></div><br>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What's the problem with ur testing code?

Comment: i need full sir i have on top and bottom but the right side and left side is my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/z2gtf7pm/)**

Actually, there's no need to manipulate background-color in animation keyframe and both coordinates - for initial hiding of the lines it's enough to set their WIDTH /HEIGHT to 0px and then animate them. For TOP and BOTTTOM lines animate width, while for LEFT and RIGHT ones work with height. For BOTTOM and LEFT lines "left" and "top" coordinates are also animated accordingly, since these lines move out from the opposite horizontal/vertical corners of the screen.

```
@keyframes mybottom {
   0%    {width:0px; left:100%;}
   100%   {width:100%; left:0;}
}

@keyframes myleft {
   0%  {top:100%; height:0}
   100%  {top:0; height:100% }
 }
```

Then, add animation-delay for each line, summing up their time of appearing on the screen one after another.

Also add animation-fill-mode: forwards; so the lines don't disappear after animation has ended.

P.S. I didn't look and copy FITCH.com code, it might be same, i don't know.